# Unity: Unable to change audiosource OnClick UI button?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I want to change an AudioSource(Clicksound) to a different AudioSource(DrumSound)
when ui button is click during gameplay.The code runs but the change of AudioSource never changes from ClickSound to Drumsound,below is the code i use

```
AudioSource Sound;
public AudioSource DrumSound;
public AudioSource ClickSound;

void Start () {

    Sound = ClickSound;
    Time.timeScale = 0;

}

public void drumClicked()
{
    Sound = DrumSound;
    SettingCanvas.SetActive (false);
}
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Piviot" && Time.timeScale != 0) {
        Sound.Play ();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is not complete. What is Sound, clickSound and DrumSound and how are they defined? You need to describe what's not working? Whatt do you expect to happen?

Comment: i want to change the AudioSource from clickSound to drumsound

Comment: How do you know that the audiosource change code is not working? Did you try to play it? How about your `SettingCanvas.SetActive`? Does that work too?

Comment: yes SettingCanvas.SetActive run when the button is clicked

Comment: Ok, good.  
How do you know that the audiosource change code is not working? Did you try to play it?

Comment: yes "Sound" is played every time when the object enters OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: Ok. I see. You want to show me how you play the sound in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function?

Comment: That seems ok to me. If `drumClicked()` is not called before `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called, ClickSound would play. I hope you understand this. Put `Debug.Log` in drumClicked function and other `Debug.Log`  in the `OnTriggerEnter2D`. This will tell you if drumClicked  function is being called before  `OnTriggerEnter2D`.....